# Making the Android Application searchable in the launcher with a keyword

Tags: java, android, kotlin, search

Our clients wants to have a feature in the app where they can search app with another keyword in the launcher like "kiwi" but the app name is "blueberry"

So far what we've tried:

- Searchables
- Shortcuts
  this doesn't even bring the app show up with the keyword instead of the app name in the launcher.

like in the iOS there's this corespotlight framework where can have this feaature to search the app with different keyword.

But so far no success, is there a way to get this done in the android side?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423325/1827254